# Install Windows on 250GB mSATA SSD - Dell XPS 15 (9530)

Tags: windows, ssd, dell-xps

I recently purchased crucial 250GB mSATA SSD to be replaced with 32GB mSATA which came in laptop.

Currently I've not replaced the drive in laptop, I saw youtube video showing the method of replacing the drive. My laptop is remaining with 2 months Business warranty.

1. I just wonder that can I install Windows in mSATA 250GB SSD and use 1TB HDD as a built-in storage?
2. If yes, how can I do windows installation or shall I ask Dell support as it is still in warranty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that, there was mSata slot available which had the default 32GB. I replaced it and installed Windows in it. It worked like a charm. But someone stole my laptop after 2 weeks of installation, which is a pity.

Answer (score 0):

I did this on my Dell with no problem.  On mine, I had to sacrifice the DVD drive to add the 2nd drive, but aside from that it was smooth.  I just imaged my original drive to the new one and I was off and going.

Comment: There is no DVD or CD Drive in this model. And I'm talking about mSATA SSD.

Comment: Yes.  I took a Dell laptop with an existing Windows installation on a HDD, imaged that drive to an mSATA SSD, and made that SSD the primary boot drive.  My particular laptop didn't have an extra slot for a 2nd hard drive, so I had to sacrifice my DVD drive for a caddy to hold my larger HDD.